# Recommend design pattern for jQuery plugins - Pass options or method?

Tags: jquery

The jQuery documentation recommends having default values for a plugin, and allowing the user to send any custom values.  To do so, the user passes the custom values as an object using `$.fn.tooltip = function( options ) {}`.  Makes sense to me.

Then later in the same article, they recommend collecting all of the plugin's methods in an object literal called methods, and calling a given method by passing the string name of the method such as `$.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {}`.

So, am I sending options or method to `$.fn.tooltip = function( ? ) {}`?

Also, why is the methods object declared outside the plugin?

SOURCE: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Defaults_and_Options

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.tooltip = function( options ) {  

    // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
    var settings = $.extend( {
      'location'         : 'top',
      'background-color' : 'blue'
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {        

      // Tooltip plugin code here

    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

SOURCE: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { 
      // THIS 
    },
    show : function( ) {
      // IS
    },
    hide : function( ) { 
      // GOOD
    },
    update : function( content ) { 
      // !!! 
    }
  };

  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );

// calls the init method
$('div').tooltip(); 

// calls the init method
$('div').tooltip({
  foo : 'bar'
});
```

Comment: After further review, it appears that settings should be defined in the init method.  I am still curious why methods is defined outside of the plugin.

Comment: Everything inside the `(function( $ ){...})(jQuery);` is part of the plugin, or at least should be. `$.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {};` is simply a way to combine all the methods in `var methods` into one `$.fn` namespace.

Comment: So, I can't have both $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {...} and $.fn.otherPlugin = function( method ) {...} in the same (function( $ ){...})(jQuery);?

Comment: Sure you can, generally they should be related. Its good practice to split unrelated plugins into separate namespaces so you don't end up with some weird namespace conflict that you have to debug after 6 months. I would say the rule of thumb is if they share common purpose, data, or methods group keep them together, otherwise the put them in separate anonymous functions.

Comment: Thanks Rob!  I didn't realize that (function( $ ){} caused everything within to have its own namespace.  After thinking about it, it should have been obvious, but wasn't at first.

Comment: Last question.  So, I send the options object to the init method, and it creates the settings object.  Got it.  But can the settings object later be used in any other method?  I've tried, but it is undefined.  Thanks!

Comment: if your saving the options for later invocations of the plugins methods you will need to do that in the init method. I'm not %100 sure with straight jquery plugins but I think you can save the options object with .data('mypluginfoooptions', options). Might want to take a look at jquery UI widget factory for more stateful plugins.

Comment: As for `(function( $ ){...})(jQuery);` semantically speaking it is creating an anonymous scope, because, when you think about it, creating a namespace with no name just leaves you with space ;)